# Don't show hexagram in label how font IOS < 13 swift 4

Tags: swift4

I don't understand why label not show my hexagram. Simulator IOS < 13 not show, IOS > 13 all ok.
I try change font to system but that not help. That my code.

```
let hierogliph: UILabel = {
    let hierogliph = UILabel()
    hierogliph.text = "䷄"
    hierogliph.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2129859924, green: 0.161139518, blue: 0.1228835955, alpha: 1)
    hierogliph.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    hierogliph.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    hierogliph.textAlignment = .center
    hierogliph.font = UIFont(name: "IM_FELL_Double_Pica_SC", size: 100)
    hierogliph.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return hierogliph
}()
```

Foto Simulator IOS 12.2 and IOS 13.3 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIxaf.jpg)

Thank for help.

Answer (score 1):

Found answer. Found a font that supports hexagram - DejaVuSans. Add font to project